# tex4ebook displays accents as wrong characters

Tags: luatex, windows, accents, cyrillic, tex4ebook

I'm trying to make an ebook, on *windows 7 sp1*, with both italian and cyrillic (and chinese in future).

Minimum example with **LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.11)**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Dejavu Serif}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
%
\begin{document}
aeeiou

\'a\'e\'i\'o\'u

àèéìòù

пожалуйста
\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex.exe works fine:

[image: Compiling with lualatex.exe works fine:]

but it does not with:

`C:\PATH>tex4ebook.exe -l .\file.tex "html5,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"`

that gives:

[image: Bad result in ebook]

The problem is already there in the html file.

I have also tried the command without the options, i.e. `C:\PATH>tex4ebook.exe -l .\file.tex`.

The same apply with **pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11)**, `C:\PATH>tex4ebook.exe .\file.tex` and:

```
...
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,italian]{babel}
...
\foreignlanguage{russian}{пожалуйста}
```

This example misses the cyrillic hen compiled with lualatex, but does not solve the accents problem either:

[image: Worst problem]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I started there with no success.

Comment: What TeX distribution do you use? I can compile your first example using TL 2020.

Comment: The second example works when you switch `T1` and `T2A` encodings: `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: I answered in the post.

Comment: I tried your starting example and converted it in a current, up-to-date miktex with `tex4ebook -l -t  ebook.tex`. This worked without problem. A current Calibre shows all the accented chars, and the html file is ok too. Can you put your output files somewhere for inspection?

Comment: Please find all the files at: [this shared folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8pf9xssneavryk8/AACJ5kZ6upIDtoYtdTPAiaTaa?dl=0)

_Compiling.PNG_ shows how I compile.

Comment: I can confirm that the Epub file you shared has a wrong encoding, but I cannot reproduce it with your TeX file when I compile it using `tex4ebook -l LaProfeziaRotschild.tex`. Maybe you have an older version of TeX4ht, tex4ebook or LuaXML somewhere in your local TEXMF tree?

Comment: can you compile with `tex4ebook -a debug  -l LaProfeziaRotschild.tex > output.log` and then make `output.log` available?

Answer (score 1):

I solved updating in MikTex console like in the following:

[image: A few updates]

Nothing very old, but something needed a repair. I don't know what the exact problem was.